# Linq.Where( List.Contains(Value) ) does not work on Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

Code snippet

```
var list = 
(from item in entitySet.Clients.AsQueryable()
where listOfId.Contains(item.ID.ToString())
select item).ToList();
```

Error Message

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = 
(from item in entitySet.Clients
join id in listOfId on item.ID equals id
select item).ToList();
```